# Create an array and show each item number of times determined by selected option in KnockoutJs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

There is a drop-down:

```
 <div class="divInfoMargin">
        There are
        <select data-bind="options: numberOfChildren" class="mscSelect"></select>
 </div>
```

I need to need to display the below selected number of times above:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: children">
        <div>
            Name: <input data-bind="value: name" type="text" />
            Date Of Birth <input type="text" data-bind="value: dob" class="datepicker" />
            Residence :
            <select data-bind="value: residence" name="residence" id="residence">
                <option value="0">1</option>
                <option value="1">2</option>
                <option value="2">3</option>

            </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

Knockout viewmodel and some rough ideas:

```
function Child(name, dob) {
        var self = this;
        self.name = name;
        self.dob = dob;
}

function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.numberOfChildren = ko.observableArray(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']);

    //this array needs to be added to:
    self.children = ko.observableArray([]);

    //self.addChild = function() {
    //    self.children.push(new Child(""));
    //};

      //This is not working code:
      self.allChildren = ko.computed(function () {
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < self.numberOfChildren().value; i++) {
          self.children.push(new Child(""));
      }    
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

I'm totally new to KO and confused. Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tenonic/2prhq5v2/2/)

Comment: Your select for children isnt adding the selected value anywhere. You can do a subscribe to that value and then call a function to add it to a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two main problems with your code:

1) Your select needs a value binding to hold the selected value; you can't do `self.numberOfChildren().value`, you'll need a viewmodel observable to hold that value.  (So your data-bind should be something like `<select data-bind="options: numberOfChildren, value: currentNumberOfChildren">`

2) Instead of trying to use a computed to populate an observable array, you should either just have the computed return the array that you want, or have an observable array with a subscription that populates it.

Computed that returns the array:

```
self.children = ko.computed(function () {
    var children = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < self.currentNumberOfChildren(); i++) {
        children.push(new Child(""));
    }   
    return children;
});
```

Observable Array with subscription:

```
self.children = ko.observableArray([]);
//Update self.children wehenver currentNumberOfChildren changes
self. currentNumberOfChildren.subscribe(function () {
    var children = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < self.currentNumberOfChildren(); i++) {
        children.push(new Child(""));
    }   
    self.children(children);
});
```

The first is simpler, but it's not an observable array, and thus doesn't have the helper methods like `self.children.push` (in fact, it's read only), but personally I'd go the first route.

(Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wp40qy9d/1/))

Answer (score 1):

I have slightly modified your code, you needed to set a selected value in your select and then use it in your computed, you had the right idea though.

**HTML**

```
<select data-bind="options: numberOfChildren, value: selectedNumberOfChildren" class="mscSelect"></select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    self.selectedNumberOfChildren = ko.observable();
    self.allChildren = ko.computed(function () {
        var total = 0;
        self.children.removeAll();
        for (var i = 0; i < self.selectedNumberOfChildren(); i++) {
            self.children.push(new Child(""));
        }    
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2prhq5v2/5/